# how to get XML object from HTML document in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have to retrieve  hier2 object in jquery from following HTML code in ASPX page

```
<div>
<hier2:hierarchy >
 <hier:x1></hier:x1>
<hier2:hierarchy >
</div>
```

I trier document.all.hier2 in IE 11 and its not working

what is the best approach to do this.

Comment: `document.all` really? use `document.getElementsByTagName` or `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: Is there any equivalent code in jquery for document.getElementsByTagName("hier2:hierarchy");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply put:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("hier2:hierarchy");
```

returns a node list you can loop over containing all the `hier2:hierarchy` nodes.

---

More elaborate:

Those elements (or nodes) are part of the ***D***ocument **O**bject **M**odel (DOM). In the past IE (and others) supported `document.all`. It's now deprecated. How to traverse the DOM. The DOM is a tree that contains a root and its children, grandchildren, etc.

basics:

- `document`: This is the master object. The *root* of the page. All other elements are a descendant of this root.
- `document.documentElement`: representing the `HTML-element` of the page.

Traversal:

- `document.getElementById`: allows you to select a single element based upon its `ID`-attribute.
- `document.getElementsByTagName`: allows you to select multiple nodes based upon the `node name`.
- `document.getElementsByClassName`: allows you to select multiple nodes based upon the node's `class`.
- `document.querySelector`: select a single node using [`css-selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)
- `document.querySelectorAll`: same as the above, only for selecting multiple elements.
- `children` or `childNodes`: a subtle difference, the first selects content nodes, while the latter selects all the nodes that are direct children (in the form of a node list) of an element.
- `parentNode` or `parentElement`: select the parent element of the current element.
- `previousSibling` or `nextSibling`: select the previous or next element.

Many more options here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

Some examples:

plain:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("hier2:hierarchy");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
  {
    document.querySelector("#display").innerHTML += elements[i].nodeName; //select the display div using css selector #display
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <hier2:hierarchy>
    <hier:x1></hier:x1>
  </hier2:hierarchy>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

In jQuery

```js
  $("hier2\\:hierarchy").each(function() {

    $("#display").html(this.nodeName);
  });


//$("hier2\\:hierarchy") is used to select the elements, mind the \\ to escape!
//each is used to traverse all the elements.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <hier2:hierarchy>
    <hier:x1></hier:x1>
  </hier2:hierarchy>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Special reminder here:
In using `hier2:hierarchy` will fail. You need to escape the `:` with `\\:` to

```
$("hier2\\:hierarchy")
```

Comment: Is there any equivalent code in juqery for document.getElementsByTagName("hier2:hierarchy");